# Spring Boot: How can I redirect user to login/signup page if they try to access content by typing in the url of the content

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

So i am new to spring boot and I want to redirect a user to the login/signup page if they are not in session and try to access the url of the content by typing it in.

for example if i am in http://localhost:8080/ (which is the login/signup page) and I typed in http://localhost:8080/someContent to try to access it i want it to redirect back to login/signup since user is not logged in/in session.

i tried this, here is my controller:

@RequestMapping("/ideas")

public String home(HttpSession session, Model model) {

```
Long uID = (Long) session.getAttribute("userId");
User user = userService.findById(uID);
if ( uID == null || user == null) {
    
    return "redirect:/";
}
Iterable<Idea> ideas = ideaService.allIdeasH();
model.addAttribute("ideas", ideas);
model.addAttribute("user", user);
return "index.jsp";
```

}

this is not working though. any ideas??

Comment: and what is happening?

Comment: Im getting a white label error saying id must not be null

Comment: what are you getting in please of uId

Comment: It's just not recognizing that the id is null then redirecting

Comment: I would suggest that you not do `User user = userService.findById(uID);` if `uID` is null.